# Filehandle open() and the split variable

Tags: perl, argv

I am a beginner in Perl.
What I do not understand is the following:

To write a script that can:

- Print the lines of the file $source with a comma delimiter.
- Print the formatted lines to an output file.
- Allow this output file to be specified in command-line.

Code:

```
my ( $source, $outputSource ) = @ARGV;
open( INPUT, $source ) or die "Unable to open file $source :$!";
```

Question: I do not understand how one can specify in the command line, upon starting to write the code the text of the output file.

Answer (score 2):

I would rely on redirection operator in the shell instead, such as:

```
script.pl input.txt > output.txt
```

Then it is a simple case of doing this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<ARGV>) {
    s/\n/,/;
    print;
}
```

Then you can even merge several files with `script.pl input1.txt input2.txt ... > output_all.txt`. Or just do one file at the time, with one argument.

Comment: Dear all,concerning the open filehandle I would be grateful if you could explain to me what the following expression means:             # open a fh for output
open( OUT, ">" . $outputName ). Why is there a dot before $outputName and shouldn't $outputName be double quoted as well? I would be grateful for your help. Maria

Comment: @marig Well, as it happens, it can be either a dot or a comma, because `open` takes either two or three arguments. A comma will be considered three args, a dot will be considered two args. The file name does not need double quotes if it is in a variable.

Comment: Dear TLP,Ok,yes-just being kind (and thankful) for your effort/response. Some people, that help with their replies, might find it rewarding, not necessarily ofcourse. Maria

Comment: @marig Yes, I know. It is appreciated to hear thanks. Just so long as you know it is not required of you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right I hope this example can help.

Program:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Check input and output file as arguments in command line.
die "Usage: perl $0 input-file output-file\n" unless @ARGV == 2;
my ( $source, $output_source ) = @ARGV;

## Open both files, one for reading and other for writing.
open my $input, "<", $source or 
        die "Unable to open file $source : $!\n";
open my $output, ">", $output_source or 
        die "Unable to open file $output_source : $!\n";

## Read all file line by line, substitute the end of line with a ',' and print
## to output file.
while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
        $line =~ tr/\n/,/;
        printf $output "%s", $line;
}

close $input;
close $output;
```

Execution:

```
$ perl script.pl infile outfile
```

Comment: Dear Birei,thank you very much for your reply, I would like to ask you the following: a) what is the meaining of a comma delimiter and a tab delimiter? Do these create arrrays rather than $files? b)what is the meaning of: printf $output "%s", $line; (the "%s").I look forward to hearing from you.Maria